# Mobile Outlook not working for one account

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have ONE account that is not syncing on mobile devices, either Android or iPhone. Other accounts work fine on both devices. So by process of elimination, it is apparent that it's the specific account, not the app or the phones. Desktop OWA works just fine for this user. Server is onsite Exchange 2016. Mobile Outlook works for everyone else. Normally it doesn't throw any errors, just has empty inbox as if it was a brand new mailbox. Even when sending, it silently goes into the Sent folder but doesn't actually send.

A few days ago while troubleshooting, this error popped up: https://photos.app.goo.gl/m7UHbfMRsSkPWALi8

I tried to search for it but Google returns very limited results and they reference Office 365 login issues, which does not apply to me.

On the same phones where Outlook doesn't work for this user, a third party app Spark works just fine, sending and receiving.

If I don't find an easier way, I will recreate the account and mailbox, but that is a nuclear option I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that I cannot open the error messages, could you post this error messages as picture?

Could you try to run [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365Eas/input) to test activesync? Is there any error messages for you?

To avoid recreating mailbox, you could try to migrate this mailbox to another database which will recover the mailbox and then you could check if this issue continues.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was NTFS permissions on the user account.

ADUC > {user} > Properties > Security > Advanced > Enable inheritance

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, you could mark your solution as best answer if some people encounter the same issue, they could find the solution quickly:)